# Pre-hover color near the top of the link

Tags: css, css-transitions

My client is seeing a strange artifact of top of the links on hover showing the pre-hover color, in this website: http://mfctest2.no-ip.org/ (apparently on pages other than homepage).

This is what it looks like to them: [image]

They are seeing it in Google Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) - but I'm not seeing it in my Chrome 56.

My CSS code is:

```
.main-navigation li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0 5px;
    font-family: tradeGothicCn18;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    transition: color .3s;
}
.main-navigation a:hover {
    color: #e31e2d;
}
.main-navigation li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #e31e2d;
}
.home .main-navigation a {
   color: #ffffff;
}
.home .main-navigation a:hover {
    color: #e31e2d;
}
```

Have any of you experienced something like this? What would be a good solution?

Comment: Auth required to view link.

Comment: @BenM just curious, what's wrong with saying "hi fellow supergeeks"?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Nothing per se, but it's just generally verbose and not required for the question. Same as ending with "Thanks, Me.", etc.

Comment: Sorry! @BenM - thanks for reminding! Link changed to a better one.

Comment: I also see the artifacts on the homepage, FWIW (56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)). It's likely a font rendering issue.

Comment: Hmm, that could be it! Thank you BenM - what do you think could be the solution?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov Try replacing the font with a basic system font like Arial or Times and see if the problem still exists. If it doesn't then its a font rendering issue

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov Just try specifying the font as `sans-serif`, and see if the problem remains.

Comment: Thank you, will do.

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov This is a Mac issue I believe. Is your client viewing this on a Mac? I looked at the site in Chrome on Windows and no problems. I then looked at the site on Chrome in a Mac and I saw the problem (both same versions of Chrome btw)

Comment: I would try using a service like [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and using the font files it generates. In the past I had some issues like this and I solved it by doing this because I think font squirrel will like normalize the font files for both windows and mac. Worth a shot.

Comment: Just checked with sans-serif and the issue is gone. So it IS the font rendering issue. If I were to keep that font, what could be a good way to solve it? Any recommendations?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov no problem. If you use Font Squirrel check the "expert" options and go through them. I had an issue with "Vertical height metrics" or something. Ultimately though I think you need a better font file then the one you currently have.